# c# - Trying to refactor functional programming block

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I am trying to refactor this code wherein there is a difference whether an object is in a cache or not. If it's not in cache, then consume an external API and return result to a lambda expression variable. If it is, use the cached variable.

My issue is that I think the code block is written twice with the only difference is the variable.

```
  var cacheHit = _cache.TryGetValue("ClientUserId", out string cachedUser);
  if (!cacheHit)
  {
      await _userM.GetUserAsync(
       dbData.CreateEmployeeID.ToString(),
        cancellationToken)
        .MapOnFailure(failure => new AppF(failure.Message, failure.Exception))
        .DoAsync(async user =>
        {
        _cache.Set("ClientUserId", user.ClientUserId, cacheExpiration);

        var opsRequest = new OperationStatusRequest();

        var results = await _monitoringService.LogHttpRequestResponseAsync(
            operationStatusRequest,
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(cRequest),
            async () =>
                await _client.DetailsAsync(user.ClientUserId, cancellationToken) //from API call
        .DoAsync(async _ =>
        {
            //code here
        }
        ).DoOnFailureAsync(async _ =>
        {
             //code here
        });

        }); //user
  }
  else
  {
      //don't call GetUserAsync if user is already cached, proceed with the operation

        var opsRequest = new OperationStatusRequest();

        var results = await _monitoringService.LogHttpRequestResponseAsync(
            operationStatusRequest,
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(cRequest),
            async () =>
                await _client.DetailsAsync(cachedUser, cancellationToken) //cachedUser
        .DoAsync(async _ =>
        {
            //code here
        }
        ).DoOnFailureAsync(async _ =>
        {
             //code here
        });

  }
```

I have placed a comment on the main difference but the code in if and else block pretty much follows the same operation.

Is there a way that I can write the if-else block without re-writing the whole implementation twice?

Comment: Move the common code outside of the if/else blocks.

Comment: If I move the common code, there will be a warning about async without an await.

Comment: Why would you remove the await?

Comment: you would need to make the new method awaitable

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).